# Social Network Database Design - Friend/Block Relationships

Tags: sql-server, database-design, social-networking

I'm working on a social networking site and need users to be able to friend each other and/or block each other. The way I see it, 2 users can either be *Friend*, *Pending*, *Block*, or *NULL*. I'd like to have a single view that shows a single row for each confirmed relationship. My view properly shows the relationship but I had to do a workaround to only show 1 row/relationship without unioning the table with itself and swapping the order or Requestor and Requestee.

Anybody have any ideas about how to clean this up?

Thanks,
  - Greg

Relationship Table:

> Requestor (int) | Requestee (int) | ApprovedTimestamp (smalldatetime) | IsBlock (bit)

vwRelationship View:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
                      CASE WHEN f.Requestor < f.Requestee THEN f.Requestor ELSE f.Requestee END AS UserA, 
                      CASE WHEN f.Requestor < f.Requestee THEN f.Requestee ELSE f.Requestor END AS UserB, CASE WHEN b.Requestor IS NULL AND b.Requestee IS NULL 
                      THEN CASE WHEN f.AcceptedTimestamp IS NULL THEN 'Pending' ELSE 'Friend' END ELSE 'Block' END AS Type
FROM         dbo.Relationship AS f LEFT OUTER JOIN
                          (SELECT     Requestor, Requestee
                            FROM          dbo.Relationship
                            WHERE      (IsBlock = 1)) AS b ON f.Requestor = b.Requestor AND f.Requestee = b.Requestee OR f.Requestor = b.Requestee AND f.Requestee = b.Requestor
```

Example Query:

> Select Type From vwRelationship Where (UserA = 1 AND UserB = 2) OR (UserA = 2 AND UserB = 1)

Scenario:

1. User 1 and User 2 don't know each other | Relationship Type = *NULL*
2. User 1 friends User 2 | Relationship Type = *Pending*
3. User 2 accepts | Relationship Type = *Friend*
4. a month later User 2 blocks User 1 | Relationship Type = *Block*

Comment: I see three problems. First, the table seems to be about the friendship status, and if that's the case, storing a timestamp for the start of a friendship seems misplaced. Second, you don't record who sets a block, so you can't tell who should be allowed to remove it. Third, "blocked" seems to be a fundamentally different kind of information than "friend" and "pending".

Comment: Does "blocked" mean something different to you than "unfriend"?

Comment: @Catcall Think I should split it out into a 3 tables? (friend, pending, block) I can determine who sets the block by the requestor field, but the entire thing just seems too messy

Comment: @Catcall yes, unfriending someone would mean your relationship is null, if a user is blocked I won't show them in search results, allow them to see basic information, etc...

Comment: Then I see four problems. Fourth, NULL means both "unfriending" and "they don't know each other". (Along with it's *real* meaning, which is simply "Value doesn't exist here".)

Comment: None of these answers the question, but is valid about how you have the data set up.  The way it's described is more of a whitelist/blacklist sort of deal, where you would want these to be handled seperately, with status codes of their own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what I ended up using:

```
Table - Relationship
RelationshipID, RelationshipTypeID, CreatedByUserID, CreatedTimestamp

Table - RelationshipType
RelationshipTypeID, RelationshipTypeName

Table - UserRelationship
UserID, RelationshipID, IsPending
```

Anybody think of anything better?

Comment: What about having more than one relationship, for example friends, family, tech, following.... etc?

Comment: yeah , i didnt realize it before!